# Is this combination of UI, MVVM and MVC valid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am planning to build an SPA and I have narrowed down on Bootstrap as the UI framework, Angular as the MVVM and ASP.Net Core MVC as the server side framework. Are these proper logical tiers? My understanding is that Bootstrap is an UI layout framework and has nothing to do with MVVM. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: You could potentially swap MVC for Web API, since MVC provides GUI functionality (e.g. defining views etc) which you likely won't need if you're using angular. I don't think you need a server side GUI framework we well as a client side one. Web API just provides a way to send and receive data machine readable formats (e.g. JSON) so you can make Ajax requests to it from your Angular code. The server can handle the business logic and data storage, and Angular can handle the display

Comment: The other advantage of a straight API over MVC in this scenario is it's then easier to connect other clients to it (e.g. mobile app) and take advantage of the same business logic

Comment: @ADyson, thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Yes bootstrap simply defines CSS classes you can use in your webpages, therefore is only relevant to the View part of your application.

Angular is a client-side framework, so also only applies to the View part of your overall application architecture (although it may define it's own 'models' to aid in this).

ASP.Net Core MVC then provides you with Controllers which handle the marshalling between the View (the html pages) and the Model (the business logic which you write yourself).